# What is the ffmpeg filter equivalent of "Automatic levels" for colors?

Tags: ffmpeg, color-correction, filter

Looking at the documentation about filters there seems to be a [curve](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves-1) filter to manipulate color with the following presets:

- color_negative
- cross_process
- darker
- increase_contrast
- lighter
- linear_contrast
- medium_contrast
- negative
- strong_contrast
- vintage

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't mention what these presets do or what their parameters are. I'm looking for a simple option to take a video and auto level colors for all the frames. Does any of these presets do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the details on what the presets do:

```
[PRESET_COLOR_NEGATIVE] = {
    "0/1 0.129/1 0.466/0.498 0.725/0 1/0",
    "0/1 0.109/1 0.301/0.498 0.517/0 1/0",
    "0/1 0.098/1 0.235/0.498 0.423/0 1/0",
},
[PRESET_CROSS_PROCESS] = {
    "0.25/0.156 0.501/0.501 0.686/0.745",
    "0.25/0.188 0.38/0.501 0.745/0.815 1/0.815",
    "0.231/0.094 0.709/0.874",
},
[PRESET_DARKER]             = { .master = "0.5/0.4" },
[PRESET_INCREASE_CONTRAST]  = { .master = "0.149/0.066 0.831/0.905 0.905/0.98" },
[PRESET_LIGHTER]            = { .master = "0.4/0.5" },
[PRESET_LINEAR_CONTRAST]    = { .master = "0.305/0.286 0.694/0.713" },
[PRESET_MEDIUM_CONTRAST]    = { .master = "0.286/0.219 0.639/0.643" },
[PRESET_NEGATIVE]           = { .master = "0/1 1/0" },
[PRESET_STRONG_CONTRAST]    = { .master = "0.301/0.196 0.592/0.6 0.686/0.737" },
[PRESET_VINTAGE] = {
    "0/0.11 0.42/0.51 1/0.95",
    "0.50/0.48",
    "0/0.22 0.49/0.44 1/0.8",
}
```

For each preset, each `x/y` pair maps input `x` to output `y`, where the range is `0-1`. If not set, the filter automatically sets `0/0` and `1/1` i.e. input black = output black and input white = output white. Whereas `0/1` would mean set input black pixels to white in output. Where you have multiple pairs in quotes, separated by commas, the sequence is `"R","G","B"` mapping. The interpolation between the points is *natural cubic spline*.

---

For auto leveling, a crude method would be use the `autolevels` subfilter of the `pp` filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf pp=al output.mp4
```

What this does is stretch luminance to full range.

---

To check levels before (and after) any adjustment you do, you can generate a RGB parade for a frame like so

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "format=rgb24,waveform=c=7:d=parade,scale=1200x512" -vframes 1 frame1parade.png
```

For a specific frame, use

```
ffmpeg -ss 12.4 -i input.mp4 -vf "format=rgb24,waveform=c=7:d=parade,scale=1200x512" -vframes 1 frameNparade.png
```

Comment: Relevant update: [lavfi/curves: do not automatically insert points at x=0 and x=1](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=5c14018fc4f6ae9fcce7eaf8dd2d66cb6fbfc7bc).